# Can't open Terminal from a Python Script

Tags: python, macos, terminal

#### Problem

subprocess.Popen can’t open any file in Terminal

#### Full code

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(
                args=["open", "-F", "-a", "Terminal", r"bin/run.sh"],
                cwd='../resources'
            )
```

#### Error Message

“run.sh” can’t be opened because Sandbox is not allowed to open documents in Terminal.

[image]

#### Debugging trials

Starting the script with sudo python3 shows the same error message.

Opening another program with python works. For example, this code works:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(
                args=["open", "-F", "-a", "Microsoft Word", r"test.docx"],
                cwd='../resources'
            )
```

Trying to open other files in Terminal also doesn’t work.

Changing the virtual environment doesn’t work.

I think the issue is due to permissions or privacy settings, but I can’t find what’s wrong.

UPDATE:

Python isn't in quarantine (no "com.apple.quarantine" attribute)

The code also doesn't work when opened with python 2.7.16 that was installed with the mac

#### Platform

macOS Catalina Version 10.15.4

#### Version information

Python 3.8.3

Comment: To open word doc, you can use `import os;os.startfile(filepath)`

Comment: MacOS automatically quarantines apps not downloaded through the app store. It's likely it's done this with Python. If you open System Prefs > Security, do you see a notification in the bottom left that a program has been blocked? If you do, you can click on that to unblock it. I don't have access to my Macbook right now for more details but this should point you in the right direction.

Comment: I was hopeful but sadly there isn't anything. Also I tried to search for the quarantine attribute "com.apple.quarantine" on the python interpreters but they didn't have any. Finally I tried running the code with python2 that was preinstalled with the mac and it also didn't work.

Comment: You also need to check the script's attributes to make sure it isn't quarantined.  When I checked the Bash script I was trying to run, it was quarantined.  This is despite the fact that I wrote it myself, didn't download it from anywhere, and had *previously run it* under another name.